# It's possible to add more than one error messages for different locales in one properties file?

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization, properties-file

I'm working on web application with Spring MVC & Hibernate so I've used Hibernate
validation for my form and tried to add custom error message for entering a String instead of an Integer value but it's normally working only with one locale.

I want to use one properties file for different locales like en,tr,ar ... if it's possible..

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Why do you want to do so? I think it's better to have separate locale message files for different locale.